# New error with delayed_job enqueue method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Here's my model:

```
class Scraper

def perform

Tracker.all.each do |tracker|

    doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('http://share.findmespot.com/messageService/guestlinkservlet?glId=' + tracker.glid + '&completeXml=true') )

    doc.xpath('//messageList/message').map do |m|
      s = Spot.new({ :tracker_id => Tracker.find_by_esn(m.xpath('esn').text).id, :messagetype => m.xpath('messageType').text, :timestamp => m.xpath('timestamp').text, :latitude => m.xpath('latitude').text, :longitude => m.xpath('longitude').text, :timeingmtsecond => m.xpath('timeingmtsecond').text})
      s.save
    end

end

Delayed::Job.enqueue(Scraper.new, :run_at => 5.minutes.from_now)

end

def error(job, exception)
# Send a warning email to yourself, or whatever.
# The scraping will automatically be retried.
end

def success(job)
# Schedule the next scraping.

end
```

end

Getting this error:

```
> ** Execute gps_start rake aborted! undefined method `to_i' for {:run_at=>Fri, 21 Oct 2011 11:37:19 EDT -04:00}:Hash
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.7/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:21:in
> `enqueue' /app/lib/scraper.rb:16:in `perform'
> /app/lib/tasks/tracker.rake:4
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in
> `call'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in
> `execute'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in
> `each'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in
> `execute'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in
> `invoke_with_call_chain' /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in
> `synchronize'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in
> `invoke_with_call_chain'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in
> `invoke'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in
> `invoke_task'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in
> `top_level'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in
> `each'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in
> `top_level'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in
> `standard_exception_handli ng'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in
> `top_level'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in
> `run'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in
> `standard_exception_handli ng'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in
> `run' /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/bin/rake:19:in `load'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/bin/rake:19 Tasks: TOP => gps_start
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which version of delayed_job you are using.  The latest version does, indeed, require an options hash, with supported keys :priority and :run_at.  However, if you are using an older version of delayed_job, it works like Answer 1.

Answer (score 2):

`Delayed::Jobs::enqueue` doesn't take an options hash.  It takes 1 to 3 parameters, in this order:

- Job
- Priority (optional)
- Run-at time (optional)

Because you passed in an options hash for the second parameter, it's calling `#to_i` on it to try to turn it into a priority, which results in the error you're getting.  If you want to only specify a run-at time, you can pass in `nil` for priority and it will use the default priority:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(Scraper.new, nil, 5.minutes.from_now)
```

Comment: My version of Delayed_Jobs gives the following when I Call enqueue the way you have it above: [DEPRECATION] Passing multiple arguments to `#enqueue` is deprecated. Pass a hash with :priority and :run_at. It looks like it's starting to only take an options hash.